# JVM Garbage collector elapsed time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I want to measure the elapsed time in GC. I am using java.lang.management. GarbageCollectorMXBean. There is method in the above interface called getCollectionTime(), which returns the same in milliseconds. Now, com.sun.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean extends the above interface and exposes a method getLastGcInfo() to get the a GcInfo object. which has a method getDuration().

I want to know what is the difference between these two. I tried both of them and and found the values to be different for each collector.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from java docs

[getDuration()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GcInfo.html#getDuration()):

> Returns the elapsed time of this GC in milliseconds.

[getCollectionTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html#getCollectionTime()):

> Returns the approximate accumulated collection elapsed time in milliseconds. This method returns -1 if the collection elapsed time is undefined for this collector.
>
> The Java virtual machine implementation may use a high resolution
>   timer to measure the elapsed time. This method may return the same
>   value even if the collection count has been incremented if the
>   collection elapsed time is very short.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already read these before posting. Would really appreciate little more elaboration on the same, more in terms of difference between the two. I could assume the getCollectionTime() is the total aggregated time elapsed in this collector from the time the JVM is up, and the getDuration() is the last recent elapsed time for the collector. Since it is not explicitly mentioned, I wanted to confirm.